# How to add another axis in a parallel coordinate plot in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cswj20du/2/) parallel coordinate plot you can see another axis at the end called "species" but it is not attached to the other axis. I wanted to make it work just like in the other axis but this is not working because it has non numeric data therefore it is not connected. I wanted to know how could I make this work in d3?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

d3.js code:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 0},
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Parse the Data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/iris.csv", function(data) {

  // Extract the list of dimensions we want to keep in the plot. Here I keep all except the column called Species
  dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d })

  // For each dimension, I build a linear scale. I store all in a y object
  var y = {}
  for (i in dimensions) {
    name = dimensions[i]
    y[name] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain( d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[name]; }) )
      .range([height, 0])
  }

  // Build the X scale -> it find the best position for each Y axis
  x = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(1)
    .domain(dimensions);

  // The path function take a row of the csv as input, and return x and y coordinates of the line to draw for this raw.
  function path(d) {
      return d3.line()(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [x(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
  }

  // Draw the lines
  svg
    .selectAll("myPath")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",  path)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "#69b3a2")
    .style("opacity", 0.5)

  // Draw the axis:
  svg.selectAll("myAxis")
    // For each dimension of the dataset I add a 'g' element:
    .data(dimensions).enter()
    .append("g")
    // I translate this element to its right position on the x axis
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
    // And I build the axis with the call function
    .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft().scale(y[d])); })
    // Add axis title
    .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      .style("fill", "black")

})
```

thank you for any of your suggestions.

I know that I have to extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each but I am not being able to successfully do it. 
Instead of building a linear scale for each dimension

```
// For each dimension, I build a linear scale. I store all in a y object
  var y = {}
  for (i in dimensions) {
    name = dimensions[i]
    y[name] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain( d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[name]; }) )
      .range([height, 0])
  }
```

I suppose I need something like this:

```
// Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {

      if(d === "name") return false;

      if(d === "colour") {
          y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
            .rangePoints([h, 0]);

      }
      else {
          y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
            .range([h, 0]);
      }

      return true;
  }));
```

but it's not working when I edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each data item, replace the 'Species' value with a number:

```
let keys = {}
let counter = 0
data.forEach(item => {
  const species = item.Species;
  let key = 0;
  if(keys.hasOwnProperty(species))
    key = keys[species];
  else {
    key = ++counter;
    keys[species] = key;
  }
  item.Species = key;
})
```

See the result in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/Lkcea075/)

Comment: But I don't want to. I want in the Species where is 3,2 and 1 to have the names of Species.

Comment: See a fixed fiddle with the names: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/Lkcea075/